# HTML/CSS text Alignment and div error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am testing out some alignment issues i had in the past and trying to solve this.

I am trying to do two things Here.

1. What I want to do is move texts in green box aligned all the way to left so that its on the edge like 'SHOP BY' above. Yes Both of them.
2. Yes you can see from the color boxes, green boxes are not meeting exactly on the edge of its parent blue box. I tried everything. And i cannot find the solution.

Thanks in advance!

```css
.main-nav {
    background: #000;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    cursor: default;
}

.main-nav .inner{
    height: 100%;
}

.nav-whats-new:hover  a.nav-level-1{
    background: white;
    color: black;
}

.main-nav>.inner{
    text-align: justify;
}

.nav-links-container {
    position: static;
    /* background: red; */
    height: 100%;
    
}

.nav-links{
    padding: 0 0 0 3px;
    display: inline;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
     /*background-color: green; */
}

li {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    /* background: blue; */
}

li>a {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 9px 9px;
    margin: 0 -3px;
}


 /*li>a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color:#000;    
}*/

.nav-level-2 {
   /* display: none; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
    background: white;
    text-align: left;

}


li>a:hover + .nav-level-2{
    display: block;
}

.nav-level-2:hover{
    display: block;
}

.nav-level-2-container {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    background: lightgreen;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
}

.row{
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: row;    
}

.list-container {
    padding: 0px;
}

.col-lg-2{
    flex-basis: 16.666666667%;
    max-width: 16.666666667%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    background: red;
    margin-left: 5px;
    
}

.main-nav>.inner .nav-level-2 .nav-level-2-container .heading {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    
}

.main-nav .nav-links .nav-level-2 ul {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    
    background: blue;
    display: block;    
    
}

.main-nav>.inner .nav-level-2 .nav-level-2-container li {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}


.invisible{
    display: none;
}

.main-nav>.inner .nav-level-2 .nav-level-2-container li a {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 17px;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    color: #000;
    display: inline;
    background: green;
    
    
    
 
}
```

```html
 <nav class="main-nav">
                        <div class="inner max-girdle-width">
                            <div class="nav-links-container">
                                <ul class="nav-links">
                                    <li class="nav-whats-new">
                                        <a class="nav-level-1" href="#">What's New</a>
                                        <div class="nav-level-2">
                                            <div class="nav-level-2-container row max-girdle-width">
                                                <div class="list-container shop col-lg-2">
                                                   <h3 class="heading"> Shop by</h3> 
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li class="invisible"></li>
                                                        <li >
                                                        <a href="#">This Week</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li >
                                                        <a href="#">This Month</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </nav>
```

Comment: your question is not clear.. what you want exactly. show us by image

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for, I just changed **li** and **li>a**

```
li {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 8px;
    display: inline-block; }

li>a {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 9px 9px 0px; }
```

Comment: Describing what you have changed inside those selectors and why would be helpful. It took me a moment to spot what you changed.

Comment: Sorry about that only changed the paddings

Answer (score 0):

Is this what u want?

```css
.main-nav {
    background: #000;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    cursor: default;
}

.main-nav .inner{
    height: 100%;
}

.nav-whats-new:hover  a.nav-level-1{
    background: white;
    color: black;
}

.main-nav>.inner{
    text-align: justify;
}

.nav-links-container {
    position: static;
    /* background: red; */
    height: 100%;
    
}

.nav-links{
    padding: 0 0 0 3px;
    display: inline;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
     /*background-color: green; */
}

li {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-top: 7px !important; //here is the change
    display: inline-block;
    /* background: blue; */
}

li>a {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 10px 9px 9px;
    margin: 0px; //here is the change
}


 /*li>a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color:#000;    
}*/

.nav-level-2 {
   /* display: none; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
    background: white;
    text-align: left;

}


li>a:hover + .nav-level-2{
    display: block;
}

.nav-level-2:hover{
    display: block;
}

.nav-level-2-container {
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    background: lightgreen;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
}

.row{
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: row;    
}

.list-container {
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;

}


.col-lg-2{
    flex-basis: 16.666666667%;
    max-width: 16.666666667%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    background: red;
    margin-left: 5px;
    
}

.main-nav>.inner .nav-level-2 .nav-level-2-container .heading {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    
}

.main-nav .nav-links .nav-level-2 ul {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    
    background: blue;
    display: block;    
    
}

.main-nav>.inner .nav-level-2 .nav-level-2-container li {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}


.invisible{
    display: none;
}


.main-nav>.inner .nav-level-2 .nav-level-2-container li a {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 17px;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    color: #000;
    display: inline;
    background: green;
    
    
    
 
}
```

```html
 <nav class="main-nav">
    <div class="inner max-girdle-width">
        <div class="nav-links-container">
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li class="nav-whats-new">
                    <a class="nav-level-1" href="#">What's New</a>
                    <div class="nav-level-2">
                        <div class="nav-level-2-container row max-girdle-width">
                            <div class="list-container shop col-lg-2">
                                <h3 class="heading"> Shop by</h3> 
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="invisible"></li>
                                    <li >
                                    <a href="#">Week</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li >
                                    <a href="#">This Month</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```